# [ERROR]: training mobnetv2 with object_detection api and I get the error while training. unknown error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

```
W0615 19:12:26.293519 16220 deprecation.py:554] From C:\Users\oknor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py:629: calling map_fn_v2 (from tensorflow.python.ops.map_fn) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use fn_output_signature instead
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
2022-06-15 19:13:01.007705: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1733] UNKNOWN: JIT compilation failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oknor\Documents\Programming\TrainingModels\TensorFlow\workspace\car_training\model_main_tf2.py", line 114, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\oknor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 36, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\oknor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 312, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\oknor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 258, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\oknor\Documents\Programming\TrainingModels\TensorFlow\workspace\car_training\model_main_tf2.py", line 105, in main
    model_lib_v2.train_loop(
  File "C:\Users\oknor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 685, in train_loop
    losses_dict = _dist_train_step(train_input_iter)
  File "C:\Users\oknor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\oknor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'train_input_images/write_summary/mod' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 966, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "C:\Users\oknor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 629, in train_step_fn
      if record_summaries:
    File "C:\Users\oknor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 630, in train_step_fn
      tf.compat.v2.summary.image(
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\image\summary_v2.py", line 141, in image
      tag=tag, tensor=lazy_tensor, step=step, metadata=summary_metadata
    File "C:\Users\oknor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 599, in <lambda>
      lambda: global_step % num_steps_per_iteration == 0):
Node: 'train_input_images/write_summary/mod'
Detected at node 'train_input_images/write_summary/mod' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 966, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "C:\Users\oknor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 629, in train_step_fn
      if record_summaries:
    File "C:\Users\oknor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 630, in train_step_fn
      tf.compat.v2.summary.image(
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\image\summary_v2.py", line 141, in image
      tag=tag, tensor=lazy_tensor, step=step, metadata=summary_metadata
    File "C:\Users\oknor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 599, in <lambda>
      lambda: global_step % num_steps_per_iteration == 0):
Node: 'train_input_images/write_summary/mod'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNKNOWN:  JIT compilation failed.
         [[{{node train_input_images/write_summary/mod}}]]
         [[train_input_images/write_summary/Equal_1/_16]]
  (1) UNKNOWN:  JIT compilation failed.
         [[{{node train_input_images/write_summary/mod}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference__dist_train_step_59118]
```

This is part of the console output and if required I can share the whole output.

I am using tensorflowv2 2.9,  python 3.10,  CUDA 11.7, and cuDNN 8401.
I want to train my mobnetv2 to detect cars in images, custom object detection.
I get this error one i run the command to start the training process.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.

Try running it with TF 2.9.1, CUDA : 11.2, cuDNN : 8.1.

[Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/10673)